# Android Studio builds library projects as main application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) library to add Transition Effects to `ViewPager`. Since it is a library project, I've imported it as a module in Android Studio and then I added it to my project as a dependency. But now, when I try to run my project, Android Studio builds and runs the library project instead of my app, which's completely different from mine. But, when I run the same project using Eclipse, it runs perfectly and my app works as usual. I've no idea why this's happening.

Here's the build.gradle file of my main module -

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 14
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
compile project(':comjfeinsteinjazzyviewpagerMainActivity')
}
```

Here's the build.gradle file of the library project -

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    packageName 'com.jfeinstein.jazzyviewpager'
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 14
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
}
```

settings.gardle -

```
include ':launcher'
include ':lib'
```

Launch Configurations -

[image: launch configurations]

Comment: where is the build.gradle of the library module?

Comment: @Olayinka I've edited the question and now it includes the build.gradle file of the library project. Please take a look.

Comment: look up  just behind the green 'run' button, what is the name of the module written there?

Comment: @Olayinka It says "launcher"(name of my main module)

Comment: click on it and from the drop down, click edit configuration. Upload a screen cap (somewhere).

Comment: just one last thing, select every build config launcher, lib and default. Delete each of them (all of them), the red minus button. Click the add (plus) button, then Android application, select 'launcher' in the module dropdown. If there is another module listed  in the dropdown then something is wrong with the gradle configuration. Try running again, if it fails. Add the settings.gradle and build.gradle in the root directory of the project.

Comment: @Olayinka There's only "launcher" module in the drop-down menu, so, I guess the gradle configuration is completely ok.

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't help.

Comment: @Olayinka It's ok, maybe someone else will find a solution to this. Please vote up the question so that it gets more attention.

Comment: Could you please contents of your `settings.gradle` file? I had simmilar problem some time ago and it turned out that there was invalid order of entries in this file.

Comment: @FilipZymek I've added the `settings.gradle` file too. Please take a look.

Comment: I looks ok, given that 'launcher' contains your entry point to the app. I am wondering why you included main activity name in compile project clausule:
`compile project(':comjfeinsteinjazzyviewpagerMainActivity')` 
instead of: 'compile project(':comjfeinsteinjazzyviewpager')'